# KendoUI and Plain Javascript (No jQuery)

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, kendo-ui

I am writing a web app using javascript/ES6 (not react/vue/angular) and webpack without jQuery. Can i use KendoUI to build my front end components?

KendoUI is a very nice tool with jQuery and I wrote one app with it 2 years ago. This time I cannot use jQuery but I still want to use KendoUI. Could anyone give me an advice? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately you can't. Kendo UI depends on jQuery to be used (post from Jun/2012):

> KendoUI depends on jQuery (v.1.7.1) and cannot be used without it. If you omit to include jQuery before Kendo scripts, you will receive a JavaScript error Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined and most probably the page in question will be blank.

[Source 1](https://www.telerik.com/forums/kendoui-and-plain-javascript-no-jquery) and [Source 2](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/intro/installation/prerequisites#jquery).